# Log Analytics - Pricing tier doesn't match the subscriptions billing model

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have a log analytics resource setup on perGB and I am trying to deploy a solution that uses an Azure Automation account.

When deploying, I see the error in my log analytics resource :Pricing tier doesn't match the subscriptions billing model.

It is my understanding that something recently changed in OMS that may cause this. I have already tried to install the Upgrade Readiness solution but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use Sku PerGB2018 instead of standard or free.

Comment: why? did you just try all of them?